# ¡Acceso prohibido! Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado

Tags: mysql

Hice un formulario y creé una base de datos en `phpmyadmin`, luego cree mi archivo con extensión `.php` para validar los datos del formulario.

El detalle está en que cuando inserto los datos en el formulario que hace la validación, el servidor me dice:

> acceso prohibido error 403

Sin embargo, arriba en la `url` se muestra que efectivamente me envió a la siguiente página, que en mi caso es la de "menú".

Tengo instalado el xampp, y lo que he leído es que hay que entrar a la carpeta de configuración del apache y buscar el archivo `httpd.conf`, para luego modificar los permisos.

Realicé el proceso y reinicié el apache y cuando actualizo la página para introducir nuevamente los datos obtengo el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos revisa que dentro de tu "**httpd.conf**" tengas algo como esto:

```
...
...
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

cambiar el:

```
Deny from all
```

por:

```
Allow from all
```

Aqui te dejo el "**httpd.conf**" completo de xampp:

```
#
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  0

ServerRoot "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/apache"

Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so # don't load because of mod_autoindex_color.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

LoadModule autoindex_color_module modules/mod_autoindex_color.so
# 'Main' server configuration
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

# Inicio de la definición de VirtualHost #

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin esteban@poravo.com.py
    DocumentRoot "C:/Servidor/sistema"
    ServerName sistema
    ErrorLog logs/sistema-error_log
    CustomLog logs/sistema-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin esteban@poravo.com.py
    DocumentRoot "C:/Servidor/fane"
    ServerName fane
    ErrorLog logs/fane-error_log
    CustomLog logs/fane-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin esteban@poravo.com.py
    DocumentRoot "C:/Servidor/poravo"
    ServerName poravo
    ErrorLog logs/poravo-error_log
    CustomLog logs/poravo-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin esteban@poravo.com.py
    DocumentRoot "C:\Archivos de programa\xampp\phpMyAdmin"
    ServerName phpMyAdmin
    ErrorLog logs/phpmyadmin-error_log
    CustomLog logs/phpmyadmin-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

ServerName localhost:80

#DocumentRoot "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:/Servidor"

# Modificando desde aqui #
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#<Directory "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/htdocs">
<Directory "C:/Servidor">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AddType text/shtml .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php3 index.cgi index.pl index.html index.htm index.shtml index.phtml
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog logs/error.log

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog logs/access.log common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/Archivos de programa/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</IfModule>

EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

# XAMPP specific settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
# Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Espero te sirva y suerte.!!